# Can't add shape in Python turtle module - no such file or directory error

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to change the shape of the turtle to an 8bit link image. I have the image I want saved to the same directory as my source code (you can see that with `os.getcwd()`.) I'm wondering why I am getting this error and how to fix it. Thanks!

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import os

print(os.getcwd())


wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor('lightblue')

spaceship = Turtle()
spaceship.color('red')
newshape = Screen().addshape('8bitlink.png.gif')
spaceship.shape(newshape)
spaceship.penup()
```

The error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/colind/Desktop/Spaceship Game.py", line 12, in <module>
    newshape = Screen().addshape('8bitlink.png.gif')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 1133, in register_shape
    shape = Shape("image", self._image(name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 479, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3542, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3498, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "8bitlink.png.gif": no such file or directory
```

Comment: What error are you getting...

Comment: Could you post the entire error, not just the final line

Comment: We're sure here that `.png.gif`is a valid file extension?

Comment: yeah heres the error I got. I'm not sure if .png.gif is valid but I don't see a reason why it should be invalid. Thanks boys

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you're not invoking `addshape()` correctly:

```
newshape = Screen().addshape('8bitlink.png.gif')
spaceship.shape(newshape)
```

As `addshape()` doesn't return anything, it registers the image shape under the name of the file, so you should instead do something like:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor('lightblue')

wn.addshape('8bitlink.png.gif')

spaceship = Turtle()
spaceship.shape('8bitlink.png.gif')
spaceship.color('red')
spaceship.penup()

# ...

wn.mainloop()
```

This works for me when I store a GIF image under the name '8bitlink.png.gif'. You might convince yourself, and us, that you've an actual GIF image by running the Unix `file` command:

```
> file 8bitlink.png.gif
8bitlink.png.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 24 x 24
>
```

You're output should be similar though not identical.